# The backspace key doesn't work while editing C++ source files and it encounter a line break,Why and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, notepad++

I just updated my favorite edit tool notepad++ to version 5.8.1. But when i am editing a c++ source files, i can't use the backspace key to delete the current line when the cursor is at the begining of a line! Can anybody give me some advices?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know there's a new version :-)  I tried backspace at the beginning of the line in a cpp-file. In both 5.7 and 5.8.1, the linefeed of the previous line was removed, sticking the current line at the end of the previous. This is consistent with the shortcut mapper: SCI_DELETEBACK:Backspace.  Is this different in your setup?

Comment: Oh,I deleted the original file, then created a new one with the same name and copy the contents of the original file to it.It now works!

Answer (score 0):

Oh,I deleted the original file, then created a new one with the same name and copy the contents of the original file to it.It now works! Thanks for your attention!